# How do I check integrity of a file from DreamSpark?

Tags: hashing, md5, checksum, data-integrity, dreamspark

I have a very unstable connection and it cut off multiple times while downloading Windows 8.1 using Microsoft's SDM, so I'm kind of concerned to how I can check to see if the file is still intact once it finishes downloading. Is there a way to do this? I don't see any hashes on Microsoft's website.

Comment: SDM already checks them, IIRC.

Comment: I know the question is about SDM (that might check integrity itself), but when you try to download something from DreamSpark on Linux let's say, it will be via plain HTTP, without SDM, so MD5 or SHA1 checksum would be helpful anyway...